# Android efficient screenshots

Tags: android

I need to efficiently capture screen shots (BitMap format) from an Android phone.  I know of several methods

1: Use the system command screenshot/screencap - **p**, then read the phone-restricted image.  This supposedly takes 1500-2000 ms.  On the Meizu MX5 it took 3000 ms, which is unacceptably long for my application.

2: Use ddmlib; this is even less efficient.

3: Read the **framebuffer**, but this fails after version 4.2: reads only black screen or black figure with the manufacturer's logo.

4: Go through the **SurfaceControl** reflection method.

5: Alter the Android **jar**.  Capture the screen through native methods after grabbing the systemuid**. However, few cell phones use this compilation, so it won't work as a general solution.

6: Use **MediaProjection** in Android version 5.0 or later.  This takes only 60ms.

What other ways are there for an app to take a screen shot?

Comment: Can you rephrase/reformat this? I'm having trouble understanding what's being asked.

Comment: Even I cant understand..... It smells spam..

Comment: please, dont use google translate, find someone who speaks english and ask him for help with your question

Comment: Fixed grammar and rhetoric.